# How to transform gyb files into swift code

Tags: ios, swift

I'm reading the swift source code on github and I have noticed there are files with the extension gyb e.g. [Swift github Integers.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Integers.swift.gyb).

I did a bit of research and I think (correct me if i'm wrong) gyb is a preprocessor that the swift team wrote so that they dont have to write repetitive code e.g. dont have to write many different version of code for different int types, which only vary slight from each other.

But I dont really understand the python code in which the gyb files are written in. Is there any way that I can transform those gyb files into swift code? so it is possible study how swift e.g. Int type is implemented?

Comment: This link may help you https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-convert-a-Python-source-code-to-another-programming-language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is:

- Obtain the Swift source code, following the instructions at https://github.com/apple/swift.
- Install the prerequisites for compiling the source code (cmake, ninja, ...)

Then compile the source code with the "verbose option":

```
cd swift-source/swift
utils/build-script --verbose
```

This shows all commands which are executed, including those to preprocess the `.gyb`
files. In particular you'll find something like

> /usr/bin/python /path/to/swift-source/swift/utils/gyb -DunicodeGraphemeBreakPropertyFile=/path/to/swift-source/swift/utils/UnicodeData/GraphemeBreakProperty.txt -DunicodeGraphemeBreakTestFile=/path/to/swift-source/swift/utils/UnicodeData/GraphemeBreakTest.txt -DCMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P=8 -o /path/to/swift-source/build/Ninja-DebugAssert/swift-macosx-x86_64/stdlib/public/core/8/Integers.swift.tmp Integers.swift.gyb && /opt/local/bin/cmake -E copy_if_different /path/to/swift-source/build/Ninja-DebugAssert/swift-macosx-x86_64/stdlib/public/core/8/Integers.swift.tmp /path/to/swift-source/build/Ninja-DebugAssert/swift-macosx-x86_64/stdlib/public/core/8/Integers.swift && /opt/local/bin/cmake -E remove /path/to/swift-source/build/Ninja-DebugAssert/swift-macosx-x86_64/stdlib/public/core/8/Integers.swift.tmp

which shows that the Python script `swift-source/swift/utils/gyb` is called to
preprocess the `Integers.swift.gyb` file, and the result is copied to

```
/path/to/swift-source/build/Ninja-DebugAssert/swift-macosx-x86_64/stdlib/public/core/8/Integers.swift
```

You can also call the script yourself, using the above commands as a template:

```
cd swift-source/swift/stdlib/public/core
/usr/bin/python /path/to/swift-source/swift/utils/gyb \\
  -DunicodeGraphemeBreakPropertyFile=/path/to/swift-source/swift/utils/UnicodeData/GraphemeBreakProperty.txt \\
  -DunicodeGraphemeBreakTestFile=/path/to/swift-source/swift/utils/UnicodeData/GraphemeBreakTest.txt \\
  -DCMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P=8 \\
  -o Integers.swift.tmp Integers.swift.gyb
```